# Access Azure App Service RESTful endpoints from On Premise resources using VPN

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have an on premise desktop application and I need it to hit Web APIs I have living in an App Service Web App (on an App Service Plan) in Azure.

My on premise resources are connected over a site to site VPN and I was wondering if there is a way I can call these Web API services(in an app service) directly over the VPN instead of going to the public endpoint.

Comment: Do you mean that the web api have two endpoints, one public and one not public..?

Comment: Hi @MarcusHöglund, at the moment there is only the one endpoint (the public one).  I would ideally like to have a private endpoint I could call on the web apps, but I'm not sure that is possible.

Comment: I don't think that is possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "normal" App Service Plan exists in a multi-tenant environment so this is not possible. You would need to use an ASE ([App Service Environemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro)) to use advanced networking features like VPN and NSG.